# Server Side Validation Error show in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How can we add validation rules after server side validation in vuetify?
I need to add email existance rule after checking the email existance at server side.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I don't understand why would you add client rule AFTER getting error from the server? Or is this a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48613643/1981247